# How to get list of all dates between selected and n days before?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Assume we have date selected e.g '2017-07-05'. Using PostgreSQL, how to get list of all dates between selected and e.g. 20 days before? So expected following output:

```
2017-07-05
2017-07-04
2017-07-03
...
2017-06-15
```

In other words, I get :selected_date and :offset as params and need to output all dates in the range.

Comment: Do you want to do this just in Postgresql or is there a programming language such as PHP or similiar languages involved?

Comment: The problem is that I need to use result set in query. So I can easily generate this with Python but from the performance standpoint it's not really good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for this:

```
select dt::date 
from generate_series(date '2017-07-05' - interval '20' day, date '2017-07-05', interval '1' day) as t(dt)
order by dt::date desc;
```

The cast `dt::date` is necessary because `generate_series()` returns a `timestamp`  not a `date`

Answer (score 0):

Finally this works for me. I di it simultaneously, but a bit different way, so maybe it helps someone too

```
select '2017-07-01'::date - d.date as selected_date
  from generate_series(0, 20) as d(date)
order by selected_date desc
```